# Сохранение действия скрипта JS после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

```
<script>
var second=20;
function time(){
      if(second<=9){second="0" + second;}
      if(document.getElementById){t.innerHTML=second;}

      if(second==00){return false;}
      second--;
      setTimeout("time()", 1000);
    }
</script>
```

Простейший вариант счетчика, вопрос заключается в том, как реализовать прекращение сбоя счетчика при перезагрузке страницы, то есть 20...19... перезагрузка... 14...15 и т.д.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
localStorage.setItem('hello','world');

localStorage.getItem('hello'); // вернёт "world"
```

Можно ещё: `document.cookie`, но мне лично `localStorage` больше по душе, думаю, куки пережиток старых браузеров.

Ваш код можно преобразовать примерно так:

```
var counter = localStorage.getItem('myCounter') || 0;
setInterval(function(){
    localStorage.setItem('myCounter',++counter);
    console.log(counter);
},1000);
```

P.S. Можно попробовать прям на этом сайте запустить в консоли, перезагрузить страницу и опять запустить. :)