# Ajax-загрузка и кнопка "Назад" в браузере

Tags: ajax, javascript

Всем привет.

Ищу способы "подружить" ajax-загрузку контента и кнопку "Назад" в браузере. Т.е., к примеру, у меня ajax'ом при скроле загружается список товаров, и как сделать, чтобы при клике на какой-нибудь товар я с него мог попасть на страницу списка товаров, с которого я пришёл, но так, чтобы я заново не подгружал (скроллил) товары? Например, как это сделано [на озоне](http://www.ozon.ru/catalog/1164174/) - динамически подгружаются товары, и при клике на товар с него можно вернуться на прежнюю страницу списка товаров.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Я что-то не вижу, чтобы на озоне список подгружался ajax  (скорее наоборот, вижу, что url меняется, страница грузится целиком). Но вообще такая фича есть в html5 - называется History API, есть и библиотеки, которые позволяют использовать history api с фоллбэком на хэш адресацию.

Answer (score 2):

Вариантов полно, к примеру, можно хранить некие параметры (список товаров, страницу списка товаров, высоту скролла) в `localStorage`. Т.е. когда вы формируете страницу со списком товаров, у Вас будет примерно такой "псевдокод":

```
var defaultPage = 0;
var lastVisitPage = localStorage.userCardPage;

if (!lastVisitPage) {
    localStorage.userCardPage = defaultPage;
    lastVisitPage = defaultPage;
}

console.log(lastVisitPage);
```

Возможно, Вам поможет вот этот вопрос\ответ:

[Сохранение действия скрипта JS после перезагрузки страницы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/391088/javascript-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0-js-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B)